# How use city and country strings in json api

Tags: java, android, android-studio, geolocation, location

I am currently working on project that returns some data from json api with the help of current location i.e city & country, and current time, I some how managed to get the current location in strings but I don't know how to implent this in api link, I some how managed to learn the basics but that was not enough and it returns nothing.
**My complete java code :**

```
String country, city,
TextView mfajrtv, mdhuhartv, masrtv, mmaghribtv, mishatv,

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 mfajrtv = findViewById(R.id.fajrtv);
        mdhuhartv = findViewById(R.id.dhuhartv);
        masrtv = findViewById(R.id.asrtv);
        mmaghribtv = findViewById(R.id.maghribtv);
        mishatv = findViewById(R.id.ishatv);



        ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            String mfajr = response.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(Integer.parseInt(mday)).getJSONObject("timings").get("Fajr").toString();
                            String mdhuhr = response.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(Integer.parseInt(mday)).getJSONObject("timings").get("Dhuhr").toString();
                            String masr = response.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(Integer.parseInt(mday)).getJSONObject("timings").get("Asr").toString();
                            String mmaghrib = response.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(Integer.parseInt(mday)).getJSONObject("timings").get("Maghrib").toString();
                            String misha = response.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(Integer.parseInt(mday)).getJSONObject("timings").get("Isha").toString();

                        mfajrtv.setText(mfajr);
                        mdhuhartv.setText(mdhuhr);
                        masrtv.setText(masr);
                        mmaghribtv.setText(mmaghrib);
                        mishatv.setText(misha);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        pDialog.hide();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // hide the progress dialog
                pDialog.hide();
            }
        });

// Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);





        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 101);
        }

        tvCity = findViewById(R.id.tvCity);
        tvCountry = findViewById(R.id.tvCountry);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationEnabled();
        getLocation();
    }

    private void locationEnabled() {
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean gps_enabled = false;
        boolean network_enabled = false;
        try {
            gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setTitle("Enable GPS Service")
                    .setMessage("We need your GPS location to show Near Places around you.")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Enable", new
                            DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                    .show();
        }
    }

    void getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 500, 5, (LocationListener) this);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5

            String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();

            tvCountry.setText(country);
            tvCity.setText(city);

            String url = "https://api.aladhan.com/v1/calendarByCitycity="+city+"&country="+country+"&method="+method+"&month="+month+"year="+year+"&school=1&latitudeAdjustmentMethod=3&midnightMode=1";

if(day == 1){
                mday = ("0");}if(day == 2){
                mday = ("1");}if(day == 3){
                mday = ("2");}if(day == 4){
                mday = ("3");}if(day == 5){
                mday = ("4");}if(day == 6){
                mday = ("5");}if(day == 7){
                mday = ("6");}if(day == 8){
                mday = ("7");}if(day == 9){
                mday = ("8");}if(day == 10){
                mday = ("9");}if(day == 11){
                mday = ("10");}if(day == 12){
                mday = ("11");}if(day == 13){
                mday = ("12");}if(day == 14){
                mday = ("13");}if(day == 15){
                mday = ("14");}if(day == 16){
                mday = ("15");}if(day == 17){
                mday = ("16");}if(day == 18){
                mday = ("17");}if(day == 19){
                mday = ("18");}if(day == 20){
                mday = ("19");}if(day == 21){
                mday = ("20");}if(day == 22){
                mday = ("21");}if(day == 23){
                mday = ("22");}if(day == 24){
                mday = ("23");}if(day == 25){
                mday = ("24");}if(day == 26){
                mday = ("25");}if(day == 27){
                mday = ("26");}if(day == 28){
                mday = ("27");}if(day == 29){
                mday = ("28");}if(day == 30){
                mday = ("29");}if(day == 31){
                mday = ("30");}



} catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }



    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

**And My Xml Code**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Fajr"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fajrtv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="fajr"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Dhuhar"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dhuhartv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="dhuhar"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Asr"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/asrtv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="asr"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Maghrib"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/maghribtv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="maghrib"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Isha"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ishatv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="isha"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Please help me Answer that the city and country string I got from geocoder, how can I use that in my JSON api url...

Thank you In advance, an apology if I said anything silly because I am beginner in android studio

Comment: What kind of errors do you get when running this code?

Comment: The string city and country is not working in url

Comment: You can put errors stack trace in your Android Studio to this question, so others can have a better understanding of how to solving your problem.

Comment: There is no error stack trace,  from error I mean the string city and country is just not working

Comment: Oke, provide the response you get from an api request

Comment: This api request url https://api.aladhan.com/v1/calendarByCitycity="+city+"&country="+country+""   should return some data if string city and country works but they dont.

Comment: The url should look like https://api.aladhan.com/v1/calendarByCitycity=tokyo&country=japan but instead of writing the city and country name manually I want to determine current location and set that in url.

Answer (score 0):

You are using this url - `https://api.aladhan.com/v1/calendarByCitycity="+city`, In this url `calendarByCity` and `city` written as `calendarByCitycity` because of this you are not getting any data from api.

Need to separate `calendarByCity` and `city` using `?`Like this `https://api.aladhan.com/v1/calendarByCity?city`

Try to add this in your code:

```
String url = "https://api.aladhan.com/v1/calendarByCity?city="+city+"&country="+country+"&method="+method+"&month="+month+"year="+year+"&school=1&latitudeAdjustmentMethod=3&midnightMode=1";
```

Comment: Still not working, i think geocoder is not working